# Identifying very tiny worm

Tags: species-identification

i couldn't take a picture because i get rid from it as soon as posible. Because i thought maybe it was a bad parasite.

But i draw a picture of it at my computer. But my picture not very accurate because it was very tiny to see what it actually look like. and i cant remember all of the characteristics of it.

It is very tiny about 5 mm in length. and maybe almost 0.1 mm thick. I assume that yellow thing is head, because of movement directions is towards that way. To move, he elongates its own body then holds to surface with its own head, then let free its other ends grasp from the surface simultaneously shrinks to shorter length maybe half of its elongated length. than repeats whole process.

It was shrinks and elongates to move

it was moving like its got very soft body. and it was becoming significantly thinner when elongates.

Sometimes looks like checking surrounding surface with his head. Seem like it tries to navigate.

finally I must describe how my picture could inaccurate: it was very tiny i cant see his body parts exactly. i guess i see a tiny structures appears like his 2 pair back leg and 1 structure ball like thing attached to end. But this structures possible thickness are micrometers so i also thought that structures could be attached dust particles. And i also saw structures like this at the front end, but it was so tiny, i cant even drew because i see just barely but cant figured what was it like.

only im sure about its head and white-ish neck.

it is elongated at the picture.

So picture is representing what i see. but not %100 accurate. due to reasons i described.

i hope my questions description is enough and isn't improper.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I think without an actual picture it's going to be nearly impossible to identify. Species identification is very difficult and often depends on details that aren't initially important. But I can tell you that if it has legs, it is not a worm.

Comment: @BryanKrause yes imposible but i was hoping to get a general idea like a family or genus guess rather than exact specie.

Comment: Interesting question, and probably a little bit hopeless. I don't see how anyone could give an answer without a lot if guessing. Maybe you should remove the inchworm image, since that just seems confusing if it wasn't really "inching". As @BryanKrause says, it's not a worm if there ar legs. But a lot if insects have larva that are a bit worm-like. Maybe try googling videos of different larvas? I'm guessing fly larva of some sort. How does this hover fly larva look? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkU8YHpuAtw

Comment: @picapica now i watched this video and it is so close what i see, especially about movement type. But my things was more thinner at the body. Tomorrow ill google about relatives of Hover fly, thanks for the video.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Was it an inchworm? It fits the description, as well as the 2nd picture.

Comment: no. sorry i guess i didnt clearly asked. 2nd picture doesnt represents it. 2nd picture just here to describe how it moves. thanks for answering.

Comment: 1st picture is represents it with high but limited accuracy.

Comment: but maybe it is very far relative of inchworm. but two things doesnt fit to inchworm. Inchworms body is too bigger than it.and mainly inchworm bends  not shrinks like what i see.